# Anylogic agent based simulation: 'msg' cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, anylogic

I am working on the development of a simulation game of a taxi calling center. Agents (in population) include:

- Home
- Call
- Car
- Taxi Station

The following code is in a function (periodically triggered by an event) in the agent Taxi Station. Home is randomly chosen.

```
Call o = new Call();
o.home = main.home.random();
Car c = findCar();
if (t != null)
{
    send(msg, c);
}
else
{
    collectionCall.addFirst(msg);
}
```

It reports `msg` cannot be resolved to a variable. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: What is `msg`? Where is it being used and where is it coming from? Did you even declare and initialize it somewhere? Please include more code to your question. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `msg` variable before it's being used:

```
    Call o = new Call();
    o.home = main.home.random();
    Car c = findCar();
    String msg = "some message";
    if (t != null) {
        send(msg, c);
    } else {
        collectionCall.addFirst(msg);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this, but now it reports that the second 'msg' can not be resolved to a variable

Comment: Does the compile error says that `msg`  can not be resolved to a variable at line `collectionCall.addFirst(msg);` ? That seems impossible for me. Or it complains for `collectionCall` rather?

Comment: complains addFirst(msg)